# How to subtract full months from end_date without crossing the month boundary if end_date falls on the last day of a month?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

My goal is to subtract 2 full months from a given enddate without crossing the last month boundry when the end date falls on the last day of a month.

For example if `end_date` is 2011-02-28 and I subtract from it 2 full months, the start date should be the 2011-01-01 since February 2011 has already taken place in full. The one additional month needed would be January 2011. I tried accomplishing this using `dateutil.relativedelta` like so:

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import parser


end_date_1 = parser.parse("2011-02-28").date()
end_date_2 = parser.parse("2011-02-15").date()

time_period = relativedelta(months=2)

start_date_1 = end_date_1 - time_period
start_date_2 = end_date_2 - time_period

print(start_date_1)
print(start_date_2)
```

This gives the following output:

```py
2010-12-28 # should be 2011-01-01
2010-12-15 # correct!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to check if date is the last day of month

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import parser


def start_date(end_date, mdelta):
    next_day = end_date + relativedelta(days=1)  # get the next day to determine if d is the last date of month
    return (next_day if next_day.day == 1 else end_date) + relativedelta(months=mdelta)  # so add relativedelta to d or d1 according to the condition


for d in ['2011-02-28', '2011-02-15', '2011-04-30', '2011-01-30']:
    print(start_date(parser.parse(d).date(), -2))
```

Output:

```
2011-01-01
2010-12-15
2011-03-01
2010-11-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the number of days per month is assumed as 30 by default. Therefore, you are getting the date, 60 days prior to the end_date as start_date.
You can use a separate time_period for two dates, and pass the number of days instead of month to get the desired results.

```
time_period_1 = relativedelta(days = 58)
time_period = relativedelta(months = 2)


start_date_1 = end_date_1 - time_period_1
start_date_2 = end_date_2 - time_period
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. If I understand you correctly, you suggest "hardcoding" the specific number of days in the timedelta. However, since my use case depends on user input where the user can enter any possible date, this does not seem to be a workable solution.